# How annotate a function that takes another function as parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I'm experimenting with type annotations in Python. Most cases are pretty clear, except for those functions that take another function as parameter.

Consider the following example:

```
from __future__ import annotations

def func_a(p:int) -> int:
    return p*5
    
def func_b(func) -> int: # How annotate this?
    return func(3)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(func_b(func_a))
```

The output simply prints `15`.

How should I annotate the `func` parameter in `func_b( )`?

Comment: `from typing import Callable`

Comment: Is that the standard way to annotate "function objects"?

Comment: Yes from the docs: Callable can be used for "Frameworks expecting callback functions of specific signatures"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the `typing` module for [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable) annotations.

The `Callable` annotation is supplied a list of argument types and a return type:

```
from typing import Callable

def func_b(func: Callable[[int], int]) -> int:
    return func(3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just searching the docs. Came back to post exactly this.

Comment: Thank you @Alex. I get it now: `Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type, ... ], ReturnType]`

Comment: What if the given `func` is not always the same? Say you have `def func_c(s:str) -> float: return 0.1` and now you want to call func_b like: `print(func_b(func_c))`, then `Callable[[int], int]` is not enough. How would you go about it?

Comment: @TasosGlrs you can use the `Any` type https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-any-type or you can leave the `Callable` type unparameterized.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it just be `function`?

```
>>> type(func_a)
function
```

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. @Sebastian Loehner suggested to use `Callable`. You suggest `function`. Who is right?

Comment: `Callable` is correct. If you try annotating a function with `function` you will get an error because `function` is not defined (try: `def a(f: function): pass`). While the type of every function is an instance of the `function` class, type annotations do not (always) use the value returned by the `type(...)` function.